# Which one of the 2 examples below is the more efficient way to display Fibonacci sequence using recursion?

Tags: recursion, fibonacci

The first example is using a list to store the numbers. The second one is using a for loop.
I have trouble understanding why would anyone use a for loop when it can be done inside the recursion function itself.

### Example 1:

```
def fib(a, n):
    a.append(n)
    if len(a) == 9:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(a, n + a[-2])
    
a = [0]
n = 1
result = fib(a, n)
print(f"9th number = {result}")
```

### Example 2:

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return(fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))

n = 9       
for i in range(n):
    print(fib(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, recursion will not be faster than a loop in any realistic usage that has viable implementations in both forms. I mean, sure, you could code up loops that take forever, but there would be better ways to implement the same loop that could outperform any implementation of the same problem via recursion....
So i think recursion is better